# Custom notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I did like to ask how I can go about the implementation of a customized notification even when the phone is locked.

e.g., i have this service that helps with push notification already.

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), HomeMenuActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

        Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Checker")
                .setContentText("Welcome here")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(sound)
                .addAction(0, "Loading...", pIntent)
                .build();

        mNM.notify(1, mNotify);
    }
}
```

But, I did like to know how I can go about the implementation of something like the attached image below.[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

the appearing of notification on lock screen is started from lollipop version.So you need to set priority max or high of notification then it will be shown on lock screen when device is locked and also will be shown as heads up notification.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I did like to ask, if there is a way i can get the customization in that format...moreso, will i be able to get it that way on the home screen...be . it the home screen is locked or not???

Comment: um not sure about that.but may be u can check lock by accessing power key pressing